# Complex limit involving roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, roots-of-unity

Suppose $\eta$ is a complex number satisfying $\eta^r = 1$. Let $g(t), k(t)$ be two functions of complex variable $t$ such that $g \neq k$ but $g(\eta) = k(\eta)$. We want to evaluate the limit
$$
\lim_{t \to \eta} \frac{t^rg(t) - k(t)}{(t^r + 1)g(t) - 2k(t)}.
$$
Intuitively, I believe this limit equals $\frac{1}{2}$. This is immediately seen, for example, when $g(\eta) \neq k(\eta)$. However, I have not been able to show this in the present case (i.e. when $g(\eta) = k(\eta)$).

I have tried rearranging, L'Hopital's rule, subtracting $1/2$ and sandwiching the difference, to no avail. I feel like I'm missing something elementary?

**EDIT:** As per the comments, this seems to be false in general. However, I am also interested in the special case when $g$ and $k$ are monic polynomials of the same degree. Perhaps this is enough to find the limit?

Thanks!

Comment: The limit is not necessarily $\frac 12$. For example, if $k(t) = t^rg(t)$ for all $t$, then the limit will be $0$.

Comment: To give some more general intuition, when the conditions to use l'Hôpital's rule are met but the results are inconclusive, tread with caution. When you have an expression in the form (stuff–stuff)/(stuff–stuff), and the higher-order terms in the numerator and denominator cancel, the lower-order terms become significant; without knowing anything about them, you won't be able to say anything about the quotient. (More at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation)

Comment: Thanks @tuna! I have edited the question.

Comment: Since you've used L'Hôpital's rule, you should have noticed that (under some assumptions I won't spell out) the limit is $\frac{r\eta^{-1}g(\eta)+g^\prime(\eta)-k^\prime(\eta)}{r\eta^{-1}g(\eta)+2(g^\prime(\eta)-k^\prime(\eta))}$, which only becomes $\frac12$ if $\lim_{t\to\eta}\frac{g(t)}{g^\prime(t)-k^\prime(t)}=0$.

Comment: @j.d. I did get that expression but was unable to reach the same conclusion as you did. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that $g$ and $k$ are analytic at and around $\eta$ then both have a power series expansion valid in a neighbourhood of $\eta$.  Because $g(\eta)=k(\eta)$ but $g$ and $k$ are not equal, we know the power series are identical up to the $n$th term and differ in the $n+1$th term for some $n \geqslant 0$.  Then we have,
\begin{align}g(t) &= a_0+a_1(t-\eta)+a_2(t-\eta)^2+\cdots \\
k(t) &= a_0+a_1(t-\eta)+\cdots+a_n(t-\eta)^n+b_{n+1}(t-\eta)^{n+1}+\cdots 
\end{align}
and as $t \to\eta$,
\begin{align}
\frac{t^r g(t)-k(t)}{(t^r+1)g(t)-2k(t)} &=
\frac{\frac{t^r-1}{t-\eta}a_0 + (t-\eta)^n (t^r a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}) + o((t-\eta)^n)}
{\frac{t^r-1}{t-\eta}a_0+(t-\eta)^n ((t^r+1) a_{n+1}-2b_{n+1}) + o((t-\eta)^n)}.
\end{align}
We can now distinguish three cases:  (i) if $a_0=0$ the limit is $1/2$ for all $n \geqslant 0$; (ii) if $a_0 \neq 0$ and $n > 0$ the limit is $1$; and (iii), if $a_0 \neq 0$ and $n=0$ the limit is,
\begin{align}
\frac{r\eta^{r-1}a_0 + a_1-b_1}{r\eta^{r-1}a_0+2(a_1-b_1)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Writing these out as power series is exactly what I needed. Thanks!